# Is there any reason why the Design Compiler does not optimize a path which it can optimize in a submodule

Tags: synthesis, asic, timing-analysis, rtl

I have an issue in timing slack got from Design Compiler (DC.)

One path Reg2reg in my submodule just was fine, but that path is found to be longer in the top module. It seems that the path was not optimized by DC in the top module for some reason.

For more details, my submodules 1, 2, 3 just have no slack at all, but when put together, the top module of 1, 2 and 3 have slack violations. The violation report is on the path reg2reg, that was not reported in seperate modules 1, 2 and 3.

---

Seem that flatten the module to let DC do not optimize (do not touch or optimize away the specified module). In this case,  I need to do timing closure for top module, so that I will not try flatten it.

And the below is my update on my work. That it:
Module 1-2-3 has slack 0.03ns.
Controller module to control module 1-2-3 has slack 0.05ns.
Top module (Module 1-2-3 + controller) has slack of 0.07 ns. Does it make sense?

I thought the slack of top module will be equal to max slack of among sub-modules. Here is is controller is max contributor, and the slack of top module should be 0.05. But the result I got from DC is 0.07 ns, which nearly = slack of module1-2-3 + slack of controller. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2):

When you put the modules together you add connections between them. That adds capacitance. Capacitance increases delay. You go from zero slack to negative slack.

If you want DC to optimize these paths you need to tell it to flatten the modules before optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added an update on my work into the question.